# Numerical differnce when using openmp in C

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, rounding, numeric

I'm doing a code to solve a integro-diferencial equation, and this equation have a parameter that i want to see how affects my solution, when running a for loop in the  serial version i have a list of result, but when running the code using omp sections to split the loop in two, the firs half is the same, but the second changed after de third decimal place, but i need the same result.

What can i do to solve this?

Serial version

```
for (int i = 0; i < vetores; i++)
{
   eta = 1.0;
   D   = 1.0;
   K = (double) i*1.0;
    
   K_vetor[i] = calculo(theta,theta_zero,omega,x,t,eta,D,K,g,f);
    
   printf("K %d\n",i);

}
```

Openmp version

```
#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(x,omega,K_vetor,vetores) firstprivate(theta_zero,theta,theta2,theta3,t) private(eta,D,K)  //private(i,aux,temp1,temp2) 
{
    #pragma omp sections nowait
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < vetores/2; i++)
            {
                eta = 1.0;
                D   = 1.0;
                K = (double) i*1.0;
                
                K_vetor[i] = calculo(theta,theta_zero,omega,x,t,eta,D,K,g,f);
                
                printf("K %d\n",i);

            }
        }
        #pragma omp section
        {
            for (int i = vetores/2; i < vetores; i++)
            {
                eta = 1.0;
                D   = 1.0;
                K = (double) i*1.0;
                
                K_vetor[i] = calculo(theta2,theta_zero,omega,x,t,eta,D,K,g,f);
                
                printf("K %d\n",i);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Diff output

```
OMP                                 Serial
0 0.406062                          0 0.406062
1 0.910302                          1 0.910302
2 0.95234                           2 0.95234
3 0.935899                          3 0.935899
4 0.845607                          4 0.845607
5 0.800523                          5 0.800523
6 0.784356                         |6 0.785621
7 0.771353                         |7 0.771651
8 0.742191                         |8 0.742313
9 0.764885                         |9 0.76473
10 0.774907                        |10 0.775604
11 0.776134                        |11 0.77482
12 0.817413                        |12 0.813391
```

Obs: All my variables are double.

Some images of theta and theta2

[image: theta and theta2 for one oscilator]

[image: theta and theta2 for another oscilator]

Comment: Why aren't you using a normal parallel for?

Comment: @KenWhite No, thanks. If I re-run the code n times, the result is the same, the difference arises when parallelizing

Comment: Without knowing what happens inside `calculo`, this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: What happens if you use the parallel versions with only one thread (e.g. `num_threads(1)` in the pragma)?

Comment: Also the table of values doesn't help as it doesn't show the full double precision. Maybe make a table with the difference of the two values?

Comment: @PaulG. if use `num_threads(1)` gives the same error.